# Ball will not move in game program

Tags: java

Under the comment THE BALL, the code was just taken out from another program. The other program would just bounce the ball around the window. This program is a game identical to brick breaker. I need to make the ball move, and then I can begin the code for a collision in one of the bricks (all their coordinates are stored in arrays). Please provide some support, or diagnose where the problem is, so I can figure out some solution. All help is appreciated, thank you.

Below is my program:

```
    // The "FinalProgram" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.LASSConsole;

public class FinalProgram
{
    static LASSConsole c;           // The output console

    //these variables can be used everywhere!!! even in the methods


    static int paddleX = 250; //the paddle x cordinate
    static int paddleY = 489; //paddle y cordinate
    static char keypressed = ' '; //variable created (character) for they key that will be pressed
    static final char left = 'j'; //character variable that will remain the same, left is j
    static final char right = 'k'; //character variable that will remain the same, right is k
    static final int paddleSize = 210; //the size of the paddle
    static final int paddleSpeed = 25; //speed the paddle will move at
    static final int thinness = 15; //how thin the paddle is
    static final char again = 'y'; //character for YES if they want to play, and play again
    static final char done = 'n'; //character for NO if they do not want to play, and are done playing after they lose/win
    static int totalBricks = 18;
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
    {
        c = new LASSConsole ();

        // Place your program here.  'c' is the output console

        //setting the instructions screen
        c.setTextBackgroundColor (Color.black); //black background
        c.clear (); //clearing the screen
        c.setColor (Color.white); //set the color to white(for the font)

        //new font object
        Font TitleFont;

        //font, style and sizet
        TitleFont = new Font ("Rockwell", Font.BOLD, 60); //the font will be in bold, size 60, rockewell font


        //Change the current font to TitleFont
        c.setFont (TitleFont);


        //Use our new font to display BREAKER OF BRICKS
        c.drawString ("BREAKER", 180, 210); //must draw the string, and the cordinates after ' '
        c.drawString ("OF", 240, 260);
        c.drawString ("BRICKS", 180, 310);


        //new font object
        Font AgainFont;

        //font, style and sizet
        AgainFont = new Font ("Candara", Font.BOLD, 30);



        //ACTUAL INSTRUCTIONS
        c.setCursor (20, 1); //setting the cursor
        c.setTextColor (Color.white); //text color to white
        c.println ("Objective: eliminate all of the bricks with the ball by moving the paddle."); //output info
        c.println ("You can move the paddle left and right using the keys J and K on your keyboard. The game will be over once you miss the ball.");
        c.println ("");
        c.setTextColor (Color.red); //color to red
        c.println ("Would you like to play? Y/N"); //output the question
        //note the while loop for the entire program is based upon this question. if they enter Y, the game will begin

        char againKey;

        //clear the screen
        //Check to see if the user is pressing a key
        c.isCharAvail ();


        againKey = c.getChar ();



        while (againKey == 'y')
        {
            //IF THE USER SAYS THEY WANNA PLAY THEN ALL THIS beLow
            c.setTextBackgroundColor (Color.black); //background color of game to black
            c.clear (); //clear the screen
            c.setColor (Color.white); //set the color to white for drawing the paddle
            c.fillRect (paddleX, paddleY, paddleSize, thinness); //draw the paddle



            //BRIKS BRICKS
            int brickCount = 0; //counts the bricks!
            int bricksize = 30; //size of each brick

            Color brickColor; //color for bricks
            brickColor = new Color (RandInt (0, 255), RandInt (0, 255), RandInt (0, 255));
            //^ brick color will be a combination of red, blue, and green. These values will be assigned randomly
            //using the randInt method.

            //first brick, since i have to start from the second
            int firstBrickX = 0; //first bricks x cordinate
            int firstBrickY = 0; //first bricks y cordinate
            brick (firstBrickX, firstBrickY, bricksize, brickColor); //drawing the brick using the method brick

            //xbrick (x cordinate of brick)

            int[] xbrick; //variable, array created x cordinates of every brick
            xbrick = new int [totalBricks]; //setting up array to have 18(num. of total bricks) "boxes"


            //ybrick (y cordinate of brick)
            int[] ybrick; //variable to store y cordinate of every brick
            ybrick = new int [totalBricks]; //similar to the one for xbrick

            xbrick [0] = firstBrickX; //the first box in the xbrick array will have the value of 0
            ybrick [0] = firstBrickY; //the first box in the ybrick array will have the value of 0

            //this loop will be used for creating the bricks
            for (int i = 1 ; i < totalBricks ; i++) //it will repeat until the number of total bricks
            {



                brickColor = new Color (RandInt (0, 255), RandInt (0, 255), RandInt (0, 255)); //color for every brick(random)

                xbrick [i] = xbrick [i - 1] + 120; //where the brick will be
                brick (xbrick [i], ybrick [i], bricksize, brickColor); //drawing brick



                brickCount += 1; //will add 1 to the brick counter variable

                if ((brickCount > 5) && (brickCount < 12)) //if the bricks reach 6(max in the row) (brick count aids this)
                {
                    ybrick [i] = ybrick [i - 6] + 30; //add 30 to their value (moving it down)
                    xbrick [i] = xbrick [i - 6] - 20; //change the x cordinate to the left -20 (off Set)
                    brickColor = new Color (RandInt (0, 255), RandInt (0, 255), RandInt (0, 255));
                    brick (xbrick [i], ybrick [i], bricksize, brickColor); //drawing brick
                }

                if ((brickCount > 11) && (brickCount < totalBricks))
                {
                    ybrick [i] = ybrick [i - 6] + 30; //add 30 to their value (moving it down)
                    xbrick [i] = xbrick [i - 6] - 20; //change the x cordinate to the left -20 (off Set)
                    brickColor = new Color (RandInt (0, 255), RandInt (0, 255), RandInt (0, 255));
                    brick (xbrick [i], ybrick [i], bricksize, brickColor); //drawing brick
                }
            }




            //see if they are pressing a key
            if (c.isCharAvail ())

                {

                    //get the key
                    keypressed = c.getChar ();

                    if (keypressed == 'j') //if it equals j, that means jump to the moveleft method
                    {
                        moveLeft (); //method will make the paddle appear to move left and right
                    }
                    if (keypressed == 'k') //similar to one above, except opposite direction
                    {
                        moveRight ();
                    }
                }



            ***//THE BALL

            //draw the ball
            c.setColor (Color.red);
            c.fillOval (x, y, diameter, diameter);
            //wait
            Thread.sleep (100);
            //erase the ball
            c.setColor (Color.black);
            c.fillOval (x, y, diameter, diameter);
            //update cordinates ******IMPORTANT***********
            //ORDER OF THIS LOOP IS IMPORTANT
            x += xspeed;
            y += yspeed; //y equals y + the speed (it will go down & right)
            //to make it bounce u need if statements
            //bounce if the ball hits the paddleX cordinate + width
            if ((y + diameter >= paddleX) && (y + diameter <= paddleX + paddleSize))
            {
                //change direction
                yspeed = -yspeed; //if it is going down 5, now it will go up5
            }
            //ball goes under the paddle
            //this if statement will check if the cordinates of the ball (y+diameter of the ball) is
            //equal to the space starting from the paddle's x cordinate but less than paddle's x cordinate+paddlelength
            if (y + diameter > paddleY)
            {
                againKey = done; //basically it will break the loop
            }
            //make ball bounce from the right side
            if (x + diameter >= c.maxx ()) //if the x cordinate plus the diameter of the ball (gets to the edge), touches x.maxx
            {
                //put ball back into the window
                x = c.maxx () - diameter;
                //change direction
                xspeed = -xspeed;
            }
            //bounce if the ball hits the top
            if (y - diameter <= 0)
            {
                //put ball back into the window
                y = 0 + diameter;
                //change direction
                **yspeed = -yspeed; //if it is going down 5, now it will go up5
            }
            //make ball bounce from the left side
            if (x - diameter <= 0)
            {
                //put ball back into the window
                x = diameter;
                //change direction
                xspeed = -xspeed;
            }*****


            /*//hitting the bricks
            for (int i = totalBricks ; i > 0 ; i--)
            {
                if ((x == xbrick [0]) && (x == xbrick [0] + brickSize))
                {
                    c.setColor (Color.black);
                    brick (xbrick [element], ybrick [0], bricksize, black);


                }


            }*/



        } //loop


    } // main method


    //method for creating the bricks
    public static void brick (int x, int y, int size, Color col)
    {


        // make it the same size everytime
        int height = size;
        int width = 4 * size;


        //rectangle of da flag

        int MainRectangleX = x;
        int MainRectangleY = y;
        int MainRectangleW = width;
        int MainRectangleH = height;

        //DRAW IT
        //color of main rectangle (white)
        c.setColor (col);
        //draw the white one + fill (red)
        c.fillRect (MainRectangleX, MainRectangleY, MainRectangleW, MainRectangleH);


    }


    //method for random integer
    public static int RandInt (int low, int high)
    {
        //figure out the range of values between "low"
        //and "high"
        int range = high - low + 1;
        //choose number between 0 and 1, mulitply by the
        //range and then shift it up so "low" is the minimum value
        int r = (int) (Math.random () * range + low);
        //finishhhhh
        return r;

    }


    public static void moveLeft ()
    {


        c.setColor (Color.black);  //same color as background so i can erase it
        c.fillRect (paddleX, paddleY, paddleSize, thinness);

        paddleX -= paddleSpeed; //update cordinate
        c.setColor (Color.white);
        c.fillRect (paddleX, paddleY, paddleSize, thinness); //redraw


    }


    public static void moveRight ()
    {



        c.setColor (Color.black);
        c.fillRect (paddleX, paddleY, paddleSize, thinness);

        paddleX += paddleSpeed;
        c.setColor (Color.white);
        c.fillRect (paddleX, paddleY, paddleSize, thinness);


    }




} // FinalProgram class
```

Comment: I have tried to move things around in the entire program. For instance, I tried declaring the variables before the while loop, but it just made things work. I am also new to Java, so I only know basics.

Comment: If you really are new to Java, I would really recommend starting with something slightly less ambitious.  There are many pitfalls in developing a game of this kind; and if you don't know more than just the basics, you won't know how to save yourself from these.  My other piece of advice would be to learn to use a debugger.  This will save you hours of time, on a project of this nature; and years of time over the course of your career, if you go on to become a professional programmer.

Comment: Thank you! Where can I learn to use a debugger and learn more about coding?

Comment: Whatever IDE you're using is certain to have online help about its integrated debugger.  And as far as Java coding in general is concerned, Oracle publish an excellent series of tutorials on their web site.